# Mongoose aggregate $match returns empty result

Tags: mongoose

When I use "findOne" function.
I get the correct result.

But when I use aggregate and $match, I get empty results.
Is there any wrong code?

I should use aggregate, so I can't use findOne function.
I tried a lot of code. But I can't find the solution.

// resolver.js

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = Mongoose.Types;
const { GraphQLScalarType } = require('graphql');
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getClinic: (_, { _id }) => {
      console.log("getClinic", _id);
      const data = Clinic.aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: ObjectId(_id) } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            // do something
          },
        },
      ]);
      return data;
    },  
  }
}
```

// schema.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;
const clinicSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: String,
    crn: String,
    name: String,
  },
  { collection: 'clinic' },
);
export default mongoose.model('Clinic', clinicSchema);
```

// typedefs.graphql

```
type Clinic {
  _id: ID
  crn: String
  name: String
  //...
}

type Query {
  getClinic(_id: ID!): Clinic!
}
```

```
// Query
query  {
  getClinic(_id: "5fcf19678c032a999f9e9dbc") {
    _id
    crn
    name
  }
}

// return 
{
  "data": {
    "getClinic": {
      "_id": null,
      "crn": null,
      "name": null
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two different types that you compare with the id you're trying to match.
So you seem to be trying to compare string with object id

Clinic schema id => like this **Schema.Types.ObjectId**

I hope it helped